# VBA Macro in Word to Select and Group Image with Highlight Boxes (shapes) on top of it

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is it possible to use VBA after selecting an image in Word to automatically group the image with any shapes that are on top of it? I am creating a "How To" document for using an app. I am capturing screenshots, pasting them into Word, then adding rectangle shapes on top of the screenshots. I'd like to be able to select an image and run a macro to automatically group the image with the shapes on top of it. I am already using a macro to change the text wrap type of the image and send the image to back (behind the shapes). I'd like to add code to then group it with shapes above it... is this possible? Thanks for any tips!

Comment: This needs to be developed more showing the vba you are developing. Stack Overflow is not a coding service. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will explore this a bit further and re-submit with code if needed.